# Hide the fact that toString was changed

Tags: javascript

When modify `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL` method by `defineProperty` or `Proxy`, I want `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString()` to return `"function () { [native code] }"`.

We can fix it this way

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL, "toString", {
    "value": function () {
        return "function () { [native code] }";
    }
});
```

However, this creates the next problem:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString.toString()
```

This returns the code above (that we used to override `toString`). Is it a better way to make `toString` and all subsequent `toStrings` return the same `"function () { [native code] }"`.

---

Upd. you can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/trnj1/Lzxn8bog/12/ (there I added suggested in the bellow answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toStringNat = () => {
    return "function () { [native code] }";
};
toStringNat.toString = toStringNat;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL.toString = toStringNat;
```

but why would you want to? if someone can investigate on this level he can look at the source.